# Can I use platform specific UI in a Xamarin.Forms solution?

Tags: xamarin, telerik, xamarin.forms.labs

The iOS specific Telerik Xamarin calendar control seems smoother than the cross-platform Forms version. Is it possible to have a Xamarin.Forms project that uses the platform specific Telerik controls on some screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) or with [Native Embedding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/).

Comment: Hello, why can’t we use Native Embedding in PCL projects? It look like exactly what I need, as I need to integrate this component (https://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation) into my xamarin forms solution? Thanks!

Comment: a PCL project doesn't have any knowledge of the required native namespaces.  Using a native control in a PCL breaks the entire concept of Portable.  A Shared Library can use compiler directives to avoid this.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean I will need to change my project to a Shared Library in order to achieve what I stated above? Is it as easy as ticking a button in order to do so?

Comment: Do you think I could achievethis any other way (should I post a new question on stackoverflow for you to answer this?)

Comment: you could also use a Custom Renderer or DI to do it

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will research more on Dependency Injection, but I find it very confusing to understand

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of possible videos/written tutorials for me to watch in order to understand this better (sothat I can achieve what I stated above)? Thanks.